# distanceTo method gives no result, returns always 0.0km

Tags: kotlin, location, distance

I'm trying to get the distance between two locations,
but i always get the result of 0.0km.

i have tried 2 versions, but both of them give me the result of *0.0 km*.

1. Version with LatLng
2. Version with location

This version is with the location

```
private fun onLocationchanged(location:Location):Float {

        if(mStartLocation == null)
        {
            mStartLocation  = mCurrentLocation
            mEndLocation = mCurrentLocation
        }
        else {
            mEndLocation = mCurrentLocation
        }
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        val distance = mStartLocation.distanceTo(mEndLocation)
        tvDistanzKm.text = distance.toString()
        return distance
        //Testing...No Difference
        val currentLocation = mStartLocation.latitude
        tvStart.text = currentLocation.toString()
        val endLocation = mEndLocation.latitude
        tvEnd.text = endLocation.toString()
    }
```

This version is with LatLang

```
fun getLaufDistanz():Float {

if(mLatLngStart == null) {
    mLatLngStart = mLatLngCurrent
    mLatLngEnde = mLatLngCurrent
}else{
    mLatLngEnde = mLatLngCurrent
}
val laufStartPunkt = Location("")
laufStartPunkt.latitude = mLatLngCurrent.latitude
laufStartPunkt.longitude = mLatLngCurrent.longitude

val laufEndPunkt = Location("")
laufEndPunkt.latitude = mLatLngCurrent.latitude
laufEndPunkt.longitude = mLatLngCurrent.longitude

val laufDistanzInMeter = laufStartPunkt.distanceTo(laufEndPunkt)
tvDistanzKm.text = laufDistanzInMeter.toString()
return laufDistanzInMeter
```

}

This is my callback

```
      //Result is always 0.0km
                    val distance = mStartLocation.distanceTo(mEndLocation)
                    tvDistanzKm.text = distance.toString()

                    //Testing...No Difference
                  //  mStartLocation == mEndLocation ???????
                    val currentLocation = mStartLocation.latitude
                    tvStart.text = currentLocation.toString()
                    val endLocation = mEndLocation.latitude
                    tvEnd.text = endLocation.toString()

                    //Testing the latitude/longitude in TextView
                    tvLatitude.text = location.latitude.toString()
                    tvLongitude.text = location.longitude.toString()

                    if (location != null) {
                          if (location.hasSpeed()) {
                            val getkmh = (location.speed * 3.6)
                            tvTempo.text = getkmh.toString()
                            tvSpeed.text = location.speed.toString()
                        } else {
                            tvTempo.text = "0.00"
                            tvSpeed.text = "0.00"
                        }
                        if (location.hasAccuracy()) {
                            tvAccuracy.text = location.accuracy.toString()
                        } else {
                            tvAccuracy.text = "schlechte Ortung"
                        }
                        if (location.hasAltitude()) {
                            tvAltitude.text = location.altitude.toString()
                        } else {
                            tvAltitude.text = "Nix Höhe"
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                "keine Höhe erkannt",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            )
                                .show()
                        }
                         startLocationUpdates()
                        updatePolyline()
                        buttons()
                        onLocationchanged(location)
                        getLaufDistanz()
                    }
```

i dont know where the problem is, so, would you please help me.
thank you.

i've tried it in different ways, but always with no result.

i found no solution online , also not on stackoverflow.

i'm new to Kotlin.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're setting both `mStartLocation` and `mEndLocation` to the same object so the distance should be 0.0 between them. See your logic here:

```
    if(mStartLocation == null)
    {
        mStartLocation  = mCurrentLocation
        mEndLocation = mCurrentLocation
    }
    else {
        mEndLocation = mCurrentLocation
    }
    //after above lines, both mEndLocation and mStartLocation point at the same object
    mCurrentLocation = location; // this will have no effect on next line
    val distance = mStartLocation.distanceTo(mEndLocation) //doesn't use "location"
```

In your code above the most recent location passed into this function isn't even used as part of the formula. I think it should be as simple as this:

```
var previousLocation: Location? = null
var totalDistance = 0f

private fun onLocationchanged(location:Location): Float {
    val distance = previousLocation?.distanceTo(location) ?: 0f
    previousLocation = location
    totalDistance += distance
    tvDistanzKm.text = totalDistance.toString()
    return totalDistance
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. How can i collect the data from the distances to resume it to one distance? With an array? A list? Is there an example for it?  I mean for example ....3meter, 2 meter, 3 meter = 8 meters.... the lenght should resume in one solution. Thank you

Comment: You want a total of all distances calculated, or distance from the first location that was passed to this function? If you just want a total, all you need is a var: Float that you add distance to in this function. If you want distance from the first point, keep a reference to the first location and use that for the distance calculation instead of previousPoint.

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it.-i want the total of all distances. I tried to add a  var into this function, all i get is a crash./it is not working

Comment: Suppose your start point is London, your second point is Beijing, and your third point is Glasgow. The total of all distances would be 8143km + 7994km = 16137km, but the distance from the first point to the most recent point would be only 556km because you ignore intermediate points. Which way do you want it to work?

Comment: If you need a var that keeps its value in between calls to the function, you have to declare it outside any functions so it will be a property of the class.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer the first solution. Is there anywhere an example for such way? Thanx

Comment: I updated it to also track total distance and return it. You just need a variable that you add the new values to.

Comment: Okay.Thank you Terfour for your help. i appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Location to Km or M -

```
private fun distanceLoc(location1: Location, location2: Location): String {
        val theta = location1.longitude - location2.longitude
        var dist = (sin(degToRad(location1.latitude))
                * sin(degToRad(location2.latitude))
                * cos(degToRad(location1.latitude))
                * cos(degToRad(location2.latitude))
                * cos(degToRad(theta)))
        dist = acos(dist)
        dist = radToDeg(dist)
        dist *= 60.0 * 1.1515
        var distStr = "$dist Km."
        if (dist < 0) {
            dist *= 1000
            distStr = "$dist Meter"
        }
        return distStr
    }

    private fun radToDeg(rad: Double): Double {
        return rad * 180 / Math.PI
    }

    private fun degToRad(deg: Double): Double {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180.0
    }
```

Comment: Wow.thank you.it looks a bit complicated,like the haversine formula, but i will try it.